# Changing skins of the YouTube player, currently seeing black version

Tags: youtube

For the last month or so I've had a dark YouTube player

[image]

It doesn't appear for all my computers/locations, and I haven't been able to find any news or announcements about it. I like the new skin, and I'm interested to know more about it:

- Why move to black instead of white?
- Can I enable/disable different skins?
- Is anyone else getting to use this new player?

Comment: Google *do* have a habit of rolling things out to small test groups without telling anybody, and the black UI would match their new header bar, so could be.

Comment: you're not the only one who is getting the new YT skin

Comment: Needed pruning to less of the "what does everyone else think?" "Why is Google doing this?" which would have made your question off topic. Edited it to be more of the applicable question for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The redesign is called "Cosmic Panda". To enable/disable it go here: http://www.youtube.com/cosmicpanda

If it's not yet enabled, you have the option to do so:

[image]

If it's enabled, you have the option to disable it:

[image]

Comment: To add to this: make sure you're not in the HTML5 trial, otherwise you wont get to see the cosmic panda layout (it's flash only). Hopefully they'll make an HTML5 version of this too.

Comment: Mine works even after entering the trial. I also tried enabling the HTML5 trial after Panda and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen that ever since they had the power saving day, where you could turn the whole page black, "turning off the lights".

I really liked it too, but they removed it...

It's also possible that they selected your account for some testing, without you knowing it. Facebook does this as well.

EDIT: Apparently, they are testing [this new player](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2011/06/youtube-tests-black-player.html)

The black is probably to match the new google theme.

I don't think you will be able to turn this off.

Comment: A black screen [doesn't actually save power on modern LCDs](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/4373/how-much-energy-does-displaying-a-webpage-with-a-black-background-actually-save)

Comment: I know that ;) But they did it for "power saving day", don't know what the official name was. And also, it's easier on the eyes then white.

Answer (score 1):

Google is testing their new designs to a small group of users first. There is no possibility to decide whether you want to be in the test group or not. What works however sometimes is [deleting your cookies](http://www.aboutcookies.org/Default.aspx?page=2) and trying to visit YouTube again. Nothing is guaranteed though.

<sup>You can try not using YouTube anymore or not interacting as much as before, if enough people do then Google might decide to rollback the design, of course this is not a real solution.</sup>